# Cast class generic conforming to Equatable protocol

Tags: swift

How can I cast generic to conform protocol in Swift without declaring a concrete type?

```
class SomeModel<T: Equatable> {
    var value: T?
    ...
}
```

Code bellow produces compilation error: *Using 'Equatable' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'Equatable' is not supported*.

```
switch model {
case let model as SomeModel<Equatable>:
    someMethod(model)
    break
default:
    break
}
```

How can I handle all generic classes conforming to Equatable protocol? The idea to handle every type separated is not very good, I think:

```
switch model {
case let model as SomeModel<Int>:
    someMethod(model)
    break
case let model as SomeModel<Double>:
    someMethod(model)
    break
case let model as SomeModel<Date>:
    someMethod(model)
    break
...
default:
    break
}
```

**Edit 1:**
Method *someMethod* was added as an example to show model handling. Anyway, it could look like this: `func someMethod(_ model: SomeModel<Equatable>)`. If it is not possible to pass such argument, it would be enough to have at least *switch* casting without calling any function or with calling function without arguments: `func someMethod()`.

**Edit 2:**
To provide more information about the problem. Class *SomeModel* inherits from another class *BaseModel*, so *SomeModel* declaration looks like this:

```
class SomeModel<T: Equatable>: BaseModel {
    var value: T?
    ...
}
```

I use *switch* statement to handle different subclasses of *BaseModel* and most of them are not generic.

```
///Variable `models` here is of a type [BaseModel]
for model in models {
    switch model {
    case let model as SomeModel<Int>:
        someMethod()
        break
    case let model as SomeModel<Double>:
        someMethod()
        break
    case let model as SomeModel<Date>:
        someMethod()
        break
    ...
    case let model as AnotherModel:
        anotherMethod(model)
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Is there any way to union `SomeModel<Int>`, `SomeModel<Double>`, etc?

Comment: How does `someMethod` looks like? Does it requires `Equatable`?

Comment: @Cristik Please, check edit in the question.

Comment: For this purpose a protocol which requires to implement `someMethod()` is more suitable.

Comment: @vadian If I don't want to have a method, is there any way to cast generic class without defining a concrete type?

Comment: The placeholder T represents always a concrete type, it cannot be a protocol (as the error clearly states).

Comment: Either you should include `someMethod()` to protocol itself. OR, you don't need to use `switch` as you can directly pass the `model` to `someMethod` and do the casting when it is needed providing the type.

Comment: @vadian No need to cast type `T` directly to the protocol. I want to cast type `T` to abstract type that conforms the protocol. In context of handling model it would be enough.

Comment: Where does `model` come from? How does it end up to the switch?

Comment: @Cristik I have added more context to the question.